# Variables in batch file not being set when inside IF?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I have two examples of very simple batch files:

Assigning a value to a variable:

```
@echo off
set FOO=1
echo FOO: %FOO%
pause
echo on
```

Which, as expected, results in:

```
FOO: 1 
Press any key to continue . . .
```

However, if I place the same two lines inside an IF NOT DEFINED block:

```
@echo off
IF NOT DEFINED BAR (
    set FOO=1
    echo FOO: %FOO%
)
pause
echo on
```

This *unexpectedly* results in:

```
FOO: 
Press any key to continue . . .
```

This *shouldn't* have anything to do with the IF, clearly the block is being executed.  If I define BAR above the if, only the text from the PAUSE command is displayed, as expected.

What gives?

---

Follow up question:
Is there any way to enable delayed expansion without setlocal?

If I were to call this simple example batch file from inside another, the example sets FOO, but only LOCALLY.

For example:

testcaller.bat

```
@call test.bat 
@echo FOO: %FOO% 
@pause
```

test.bat

```
@setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
@IF NOT DEFINED BAR ( 
    @set FOO=1 
    @echo FOO: !FOO! 
)
```

This displays:

```
FOO: 1 
FOO: 
Press any key to continue . . .
```

In this case, it appears that I have to enable delayed expansion in the CALLER, which may be a hassle.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Environment variables in batch files are expanded when a line is parsed. In the case of blocks delimited by parentheses (as your `if not defined`) the whole block counts as a "line" or command.

This means that all occurrences of %FOO% are replaced by their values *before* the block is run. In your case with nothing, as the variable doesn't have a value yet.

To solve this you can enable *delayed expansion*:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

Delayed expansion causes variables delimited by exclamation marks (`!`) to be evaluated on execution instead of parsing which will ensure the correct behavior in your case:

```
if not defined BAR (
    set FOO=1
    echo Foo: !FOO!
)
```

`help set` details this too:

> Finally, support for delayed
> environment variable expansion has
> been added.  This support is always
> disabled by default, but may be
> enabled/disabled via the `/V` command
> line switch to `CMD.EXE`.  See `CMD /?`
>
> Delayed environment variable expansion
> is useful for getting around the
> limitations of the current expansion
> which happens when a line of text is
> read, not when it is executed.  The
> following example demonstrates the
> problem with immediate variable
> expansion:
>
> ```
> set VAR=before
> if "%VAR%" == "before" (
>     set VAR=after
>     if "%VAR%" == "after" @echo If you see this, it worked
> )
> ```
>
> would never display the message, since
> the `%VAR%` in *both* `IF` statements is
> substituted when the first IF
> statement is read, since it logically
> includes the body of the `IF`, which is
> a compound statement.  So the IF
> inside the compound statement is
> really comparing "before" with "after"
> which will never be equal.  Similarly,
> the following example will not work as
> expected:
>
> ```
> set LIST=
> for %i in (*) do set LIST=%LIST% %i
> echo %LIST%
> ```
>
> in that it will *not* build up a list of
> files in the current directory, but
> instead will just set the `LIST`
> variable to the last file found.
> Again, this is because the `%LIST%` is
> expanded just once when the `FOR`
> statement is read, and at that time
> the `LIST` variable is empty. So the
> actual FOR loop we are executing is:
>
> ```
> for %i in (*) do set LIST= %i
> ```
>
> which just keeps setting `LIST` to the
> last file found.
>
> Delayed environment variable expansion
> allows you to use a different
> character (the exclamation mark) to
> expand environment variables at
> execution time.  If delayed variable
> expansion is enabled, the above
> examples could be written as follows
> to work as intended:
>
> ```
> set VAR=before
> if "%VAR%" == "before" (
>     set VAR=after
>     if "!VAR!" == "after" @echo If you see this, it worked
> )
>
> set LIST=
> for %i in (*) do set LIST=!LIST! %i
> echo %LIST%
> ```

Comment: And if you need to echo an `!`, use `^^^!` (escape it twice). Otherwise the "delayed expansion" feature will eat it.

Answer (score 5):

The same behavior also happens when the commands are on a single line (`&` is the command separator):

```
if not defined BAR set FOO=1& echo FOO: %FOO%
```

Joey's explanation is my favorite. Note however that `enabledelayedexpansion` does not work on Windows NT 4.0 (and I'm not sure about Windows 2000).

About your follow-up question, no, it is not possible to `EnableDelayedExpansion` without `setlocal`. However the original behavior that was going against you can be used to workaroud that second problem: the trick is to `endlocal` on the same line where you set again the values of the variables you need.

Here is your `test.bat` modified:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
IF NOT DEFINED BAR ( 
    set FOO=1 
    echo FOO: !FOO! 
)
endlocal & set FOO=%FOO%
```

But here is another workaround to that problem: use a procedure in the same file instead of an inline block or an external file.

```
@echo off
if not defined BAR call :NotDefined
pause
goto :EOF

:NotDefined
set FOO=1
echo FOO: %FOO%
goto :EOF
```

Comment: "the trick is to endlocal on the same line" - THANKS for that!

Answer (score 3):

If it isn't working that way, you likely have delayed environment variable expansion on. You can either turn it off with `cmd /V:OFF` or use exclamation marks inside your if:

```
@echo off
IF NOT DEFINED BAR (
    set FOO=1
    echo FOO: !FOO!
)
pause
echo on
```

Comment: *Enabling* delayed expansion only alters the semantics of the exclamation mark. It doesn't have any effect whatsoever on normal variable expansion. Besides, accidentally enabling it is very unlikely; people who have it enabled usually do so on purpose.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your line with `FOR` command evaluates only once. You need some way to reevaluate it. You could simulate a delayed expansion with `CALL` command:

```
for /l %%I in (0,1,5) do call echo %%RANDOM%%
```

Comment: The delayed expansion didn't work, but this /do call/ worked on win7, for my 3 line cmd script to find the real hardlink:  @for /f "delims=" %%a in ('bash ~/perl/cwd2.sh %*') do call set CWD_REAL=%%a
echo cd /d %CWD_REAL%
cd /d %CWD_REAL%

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that it DOES work if it's a single command on the same line.

e.g.

```
   if not defined BAR set FOO=1
```

will actually set `FOO` to 1. You could then do another check such as:

```
   if not defined BAR echo FOO: %FOO%
```

Hey, I never said it was pretty. But if you don't want to mess with setlocal or the delayed expansion business, it's a quick workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, as I had in my case, when you need to be compatible with legacy systems like old NT4 servers where delayed expansion are not working or for some reason is not working you may need alternate solution.

In case you will use Delayd Expansion, also recommended that at least check in batch should be included:

```
IF NOT %Comspec%==!Comspec! ECHO Delayed Expansion is NOT enabled.
```

In case you just want more readable and simple approach, here are alternate solutions:

```
REM Option 2: use `call` inside block statement
IF NOT DEFINED BAR2 ( 
  set FOO2=2 
  call echo FOO2: %%FOO2%%
)
echo FOO2: %FOO2%
```

which works like this:

```
>REM Option 2: use `call` inside block statement

>IF NOT DEFINED BAR2 (
 set FOO2=2
 call echo FOO2: %FOO2%
)
FOO2: 2

>echo FOO2: 2
FOO2: 2
```

and one more pure cmd solution:

```
REM Option 3: use `goto` logic blocks
IF DEFINED BAR3 goto endbar3
  set FOO3=3 
  echo FOO3: %FOO3%
:endbar3
echo FOO3: %FOO3%
```

it works like this:

```
>REM Option 3: use `goto` logic blocks

>IF DEFINED BAR3 goto endbar3

>set FOO3=3

>echo FOO3: 3
FOO3: 3

>echo FOO3: 3
FOO3: 3
```

and this is full IF THEN ELSE syntax solution:

```
REM Full IF THEN ELSE solution
IF NOT DEFINED BAR4 goto elsebar4
REM this is TRUE condition, normal batch flow
  set FOO4=6
  echo FOO4: %FOO4%
  goto endbar4
:elsebar4
  set FOO4=4
  echo FOO4: %FOO4%
  set BAR4=4
:endbar4
echo FOO4: %FOO4%
echo BAR4: %BAR4%
```

it works like this:

```
>REM Full IF THEN ELSE solution

>IF NOT DEFINED BAR4 goto elsebar4

>set FOO4=4

>echo FOO4: 4
FOO4: 4

>set BAR4=4

>echo FOO4: 4
FOO4: 4

>echo BAR4: 4
BAR4: 4
```