# %RANDOM% environment variable is giving a single number

Tags: windows, windows-xp, command-line, batch, batch-file

I’m having trouble with the `%RANDOM%` environment variable in the following command:

```
FOR /l %%A in (0,1,30) do set /a results=1600 + %RANDOM% %% (1900 - 1600 + 1) && echo %%A--!results!
```

I expect this output:

```
0--1656
1--1743
2--1629
3--1887
…
```

But I’m getting this:

```
0--1656
1--1656
2--1656
3--1656
…
```

The `%RANDOM%` variable is *supposed to* return a random number, but it’s giving the same number. What’s the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: @WernerHenze, actually it’s not; it’s closer to [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/78496/).

Comment: @Synetech OK, but at least the answers in the question I linked give the answer to the question here :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use delayed expansion for the `RANDOM` variable as well:

```
FOR /l %%A in (0,1,30) do set /a results=1600 + !RANDOM! %% (1900 - 1600 + 1) && echo %%A--!results!
```

[image: Screenshot of command-prompt with expected results from script]

Comment: Thanks... By using delayed expansion, it worked the way I wanted.

Comment: You were already using delayed expansion on the `results` variable, you just forgot to use on the `random` variable. You need to use `!` in place of `%` for *all* variables in a `for` loop. `;-)`